# Validation fails on a select box whose contents are added by an Ajax call

Tags: django, django-models

This question is related to this one

[Remove all the elements in a foreign key select field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340498/remove-all-the-elements-in-a-foreign-key-select-field)

I had a foreign key field in my model which was getting pre-populated by its data and I wanted the select list to be empty. I did achieve that but the validation fails when I submit the form.

The error says "Select a valid choice option. 1 is not one of the available choices).

These are my models

```
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    serving_size = models.ForeignKey(ServingSize)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class RecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    serving_size = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())

    class Meta:
        serving_size  = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())
        model = RecipeIngredient
        fields = ('ingredient', 'quantity', 'serving_size')
        widgets  = {
            'ingredient': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'recipe_ingredient'}),
            'quantity': forms.TextInput(),
            'serving_size' : forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'ddl'}),
        }
```

I get an error on the third line

```
recipeIngredients = models.RecipeIngredientFormSet(request.POST)
print(recipeIngredients.errors)
objRecipeIngredients = recipeIngredients.save(commit=False)
```

I want the select box to be empty because it gets populated by an ajax call. Any ideas what to do so the model passes the validation?

**EDIT**

Serving Size Model

```
class ServingSize(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length = 125)
    food_group = models.ForeignKey(FoodGroup)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    dal_objects = ServingSizeManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why do you have serving_size in the Meta class?

I would use an extra field in the ModelForm and leave out serving_size field altogether.

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mycustomfield = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
        exclude = ('serving_size', 'created', 'updated') #etc
```

Then in the view I would manipulate the form to assign a **valid** ServingSize to the serving_size field.

**[EDIT]**

Alright, your actual implementation will depend on what you are pulling through ajax and how. But see the following code: -

Your form: -

```
class CustomRecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipe = forms.ModelChoiceField(            Recipe.objects.all(),
                                                widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'customclass',}))

    ingredient = forms.ModelChoiceField(        Ingredient.objects.all(),
                                                widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'recipe_ingredient',}))

    my_custom_serving_size_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'ddl',}))

    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    order = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
        exclude = ('serving_size', 'created', 'updated',)
```

Pull your data through ajax into the my_custom_serving_size_field

Your view: -

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomRecipeIngredientForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_recipe_ingredient = form.save(commit=False)
            new_recipe_ingredient.serving_size = ServingSize.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['my_custom_serving_size_field'])
            new_recipe_ingredient.save()             

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect_to_wherever'))
    else:
        form = CustomRecipeIngredientForm()
    return render_to_response('path/to/my_template.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Of course, your ServingSize.objects.get() logic will depend on what your are pulling through ajax and how. Try something along these lines and let us know.

Comment: If I do this then how will I set the serving_size field? I am using this with inlineformset_factory. I am a little new to this, thanks.

Comment: I've tried to post a raw guide on how to go about it. Check the edited answer.

Comment: I get an error which says [{'custom_serving_size': [u'Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices.']}]. The selectlist is empty and not tied to anything so why doesn't it accept any value I provide? This is my field custom_serving_size = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'ddl'}))

Comment: That's because you need to supply choices for a ChoiceField. Use another type of field instead.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought I had to do. I think I will create my own field. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a [ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), which

> Allows the selection of a single model
>   object, suitable for representing a
>   foreign key

Comment: If I use a ModelChoiceField, I would have to provide a queryset and I am trying to avoid that. Is there a way to not provide the queryset?

Comment: @iHeartDucks, no, I don't believe you can make a `ModelChoiceField` without a queryset, but what's wrong with just using `ServingSize.objects.all()`?  Unless your concept of "serving size" is really weird, there shouldn't be that many items there anyway!-)

Comment: The serving sizes can changes based on the ingredients selected. I actually populate the serving sizes after the ingredient is selected.