# Saving ModelForm data Django CreateView says Field is missing

Tags: django, django-forms

Need some help with my forms. Tried looking everywhere but cant seem to get a crack at it.

When ever i try saving the form I get **"NGO
This field is required."** even though i select the field and give it a value from the select box.

The NGOs returned are those that are associated with the currently logged in user, however even though i select one from the list click on my save button in my template, i get a validation error, NGO This field is required.

What could I be missing? 
**forms.py**

```
class QuestionaireAnswerForm(ModelForm):
    ngo = ModelChoiceField(queryset=NGO.objects.none(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    costcategory = ModelChoiceField(queryset=CostCategory.objects.all() ,widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    question = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.none(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    .... more fields below

    def __init__(self, donor, *args, **kwargs):

        super(QuestionaireAnswerForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ngos = NGO.objects.filter(donor__donor__username=donor)    
        self.fields['ngo'].queryset=ngos
        self.fields['ngo'].initial=ngos[0].pk
```

**views.py**

```
class QuestionaireAnswerView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = QuestionaireAnswerForm
    template_name = "questionaire.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(QuestionaireAnswerView,self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['donor'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):

        form.instance.donor = Donor.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

        return super(QuestionaireAnswerView, self).form_valid(form)


def get_success_url(self):
    return "/account/"+ str(self.request.user)
```

Comment: is `ngo`-s content loaded by an ajax call?

Comment: No its not, but i have other fields, like **question** in the form that are loaded using JSON.

Comment: I think the asnwer may be related with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376578/validation-fails-on-a-select-box-whose-contents-are-added-by-an-ajax-call

Comment: What does the NGO field look like in your template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman here you go '<tr>
                                <td> {{ form.ngo.label }}</td>
                                <td> {{ form.ngo }} </td>
                            </tr>'

Answer (score 0):

The challenge was in the naming of the field NGO/ngo

In my **models.py** I named the NGO field as NGO and in my **forms.py** i called it ngo thats why Django was throwing the error that field NGO is required.

Renaming the field from ngo to NGO in my field list in the **forms.py** solved the problem like so

from

```
ngo = ModelChoiceField(queryset=NGO.objects.none(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

to

```
NGO = ModelChoiceField(queryset=NGO.objects.none(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

**Python is Case sensitive**